Dual Boot Ubuntu 24.04 Screen Flickering on Start Up
I just recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 as dual boot with windows 11. the installation works great. Until I noticed that whenever I restart after using Windows 11 to run Ubuntu, it will flicker just before the login screen (after boot animation) or sometimes after the login screen.
Restarting Ubuntu doesn't trigger the flickering, but restarting Ubuntu on login screen will take a long time, about 3-4 mins.
My system is a laptop with intel i5 gen 6 with gtx 1050.
is there anything I can do to fix this?

There is no version of Ubuntu called 24.4 please edit the question and correct the version, thanks.

sorry david, i thought it was 24.4, what i meant is the latest ubuntu desktop 24.04
